# Format ETH Value Correctly

Tags: ether, etherscan, web3.py

I'm using the Etherscan API to pull transactions logs for specific wallets, but I'm having a hard time trying to format the value correctly.

This is the url I'm working with [Transaction Log](http://ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x2025B142f764004372243386A5c9D7BF5f8F769A&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken)

One of the transactions has a value of 206933340464 which in the etherscan site it looks like 0.00000020693334 if I use

```
web3.fromWei(206933340464,'ether')
```

I get 2.0693334. How can I format this value correctly?, or could it be that etherscan is providing wrong values?.

Cheers.

Comment: Is that your exact code? When I do `web3.fromWei(206933340464, 'ether')`, I get `"0.000000206933340464"`.

Comment: Oh wow you're right. Using the Web3.js lib it's actually correct. I forgot to mention I'm using the Web3.py lib. Must be a bug then. Thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web3.py` (at least the version I'm running) also gives the correct answer, but if you don't like the scientific notation, you'll have to use a format string:

```
>>> web3.fromWei(206933340464, 'ether')
Decimal('2.06933340464E-7')
>>> print('{:.14f}'.format(web3.fromWei(206933340464, 'ether')))
0.00000020693334
```